# How to acquire graph token without using sessions?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application that is utilizing Azure AD authentication. I also need to access the Microsoft Graph API for user data. Every example I have found that makes requests to the Graph API is utilizing a cached session token, but since I am using JWT obviously I have no need for storing session state. How can I get a JWT with the proper audience using a JWT with my app as the audience?

For example, here is a request to retrieve a token from the [Microsoft Graph AspNetCore Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample):

```
_userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    _appId,
    _redirectUri,
    _credential,
    _userTokenCache,
    null);
var result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, cca.Users.First());
return result.AccessToken;
```

Which utilizes the memory cache to pull the token from a Challenge() redirect sign-in with OpenId Connect cookie. However, since I am using JWT, I already have a bearer token, but with the wrong authority. What do I need to do to acquire a new token that I can use to access the Graph API? I still want the tokens to be authorized for my application id, so I would want a new token that allows me to access the API with server-side rest requests.

**Edit:** Incorrectly tagged as Azure AD Graph, retagged to Microsoft Graph.

**Edit Edit:** To clarify, each of the samples I've seen so far is using Session cookies as so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => {
        sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie();
```

However, I am using JWT so I don't have a token cached:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions {
    Authority = $"{instance}{tenant}",
        Audience = audience,
        SaveToken = true
});
```

The JWT that I get from requests to `login.microsoftonline.com` have my application as the audience, whereas the JWT generated by these samples have `https://graph.microsoft.com` as the audience. So I need to get (I presume at least) a token for this audience using only the token I got from my standard authentication request.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I am using JWT"? JWT is simply the token format and is what you would get from any of the AAD OAUTH methods.

Comment: The application posts into login.microsoftonline.com and I get a JWT from that service. The samples depicted all appear to be using session cookies, so with a simple call to app.AddMemoryCache() will populate their memory cache with a live token. The token I get is for a different audience, and so is rejected by the graph api.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I have updated the post with more information regarding the application's authentication scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse how you manage your token (i.e. token cache) with the tokens themselves. The reason you cache a token is simply so you can request a refreshed token as needed (`refresh_token`). The refresh token is only provided for certain sceanios (i.e. when using the `authorization_code` flow **and** you've requested the `offline_access` scope).

If you're using a flow without a refresh token (i.e `implicit` or `client_credentials`) then you may not need to cache your token. You generally should still cache them since there *is* an overhead cost to fetching a token from AAD and caching allows you to only retrieve a new token when the existing one expires.

**Using DelegateAuthenticationProvider with an existing Token**

All that said, it sounds like you've already got a token in hand. Since the entire point of MSAL (which is where `ConfidentialClientApplication` comes from) it to retrieve and manage tokens for you, I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to do this. I would simply skip MSAL entirely and just use your existing token.

If you're using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) you can drop MSAL entirely and simply use your existing token (`access_token`) via the `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`:

```cs
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.access_token);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    })
);
```

As for the "proper audience", I'm not sure I understand the context. Your token will need to include scopes for Microsoft Graph but how you define them depends a bit on how you are getting your token.

**v1 Endpoint**

If you're using the older [Azure AD OAUTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) endpoint (aka the v1 Endpoint) then you need to configure your Application permissions via the Azure Portal. In order to switch between different APIs (called "Resources") you need to request `offline_access` and user the `refresh_token`. Switching involves requesting a refreshed token while passing in a new `resource`. The resulting token will then work with that resource.

For example, if my default resource is a SharePoint Online instance (`https://tenant.sharepoint.com`) then I would normally refresh my token with something like this:

```cs
private async Task<string> RequestTokenAsync() {
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    data.Add("client_id", _clientId);
    data.Add("client_secret", _clientSecret);
    data.Add("resource", "https://tenant.sharepoint.com");
    data.Add("redirect_uri", RedirectUri);
    data.Add("refresh_token ", refresh_token);

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_tokenUri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Now if I want to make a call to Microsoft Graph I will first need to get a token for the `https://graph.microsoft.com` resource:

```cs
private async Task<string> RequestTokenAsync() {
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    data.Add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    data.Add("client_id", _clientId);
    data.Add("client_secret", _clientSecret);
    data.Add("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com");
    data.Add("redirect_uri", RedirectUri);
    data.Add("refresh_token ", refresh_token);

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_tokenUri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Now I have two tokens, one for SharePoint and one for Microsoft Graph. I can switch between resources by simply refreshing the token for the proper resource. I do have to make sure I refresh properly however since if my `refresh_token` expires before I can replace it, I've lost my credentials entirely.

If this sounds complicated, it is. Generally you need to build some mechanisms to manage which tokens are live, which tokens need to be replaced, etc. This is what that token cache is all about since MSAL/ADAL handle this for you.

**v2 Endpoint**

The newer v2 Endpoint is far easier to work with. Rather than `resources` it uses `scopes`. These scopes include the resource identifier and can be dynamically assigned as needed.

So while in v1 we might assign `user.read` from Microsoft Graph and `user.read` from Outlook Rest API, we can now assign both at once in a single token by requesting `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` and `https://outlook.office.com/user.read` at the same time. This means we get a single token that can be used with either API without getting into the "refresh to switch resource" business from above.

The downside of v2 is that only a limited number of APIs support it at the moment. If you need to work across a number of APIs, you may still be better off using v1 for this reason.

Hope this helps a little.